# Sintaxe consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Alguém pode ajudar a produzir a sintaxe da consulta SQL pra obter o resultado abaixo?

Preciso que todos os valores da tabela "Orçamentos" seja listada, mas ao mesmo tempo que todas as categorias sejam listadas também (mesmo que não tenha orçamento cadastrado pra categoria ela deve ser exibida).

**Tabela Orçamentos**

```
+----+------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | ano  | id_categoria | id_condominio | mes_01  | mes_02  | mes_03  | mes_04  | mes_05  | mes_06  | mes_07  | mes_08  | mes_09  | mes_10  | mes_11  | mes_12  |
+----+------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 2018 |            1 |            19 | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  |
|  2 | 2019 |            1 |            19 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 |
|  3 | 2018 |            7 |            19 | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 600.00  |
+----+------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**Tabela Categorias**

```
+----+-----------------------------+---------------+
| id |       nome_categoria        | id_condominio |
+----+-----------------------------+---------------+
|  1 | Cotas do MÃªs               | NULL          |
|  2 | Juros                       | NULL          |
|  3 | Multas                      | NULL          |
|  4 | Descontos                   | NULL          |
|  5 | Tarifa bancÃ¡ria            | NULL          |
|  6 | Rendimento de PoupanÃ§a     | NULL          |
|  7 | Rendimento de Investimentos | NULL          |
|  8 | Multas InfraÃ§Ãµes          | NULL          |
|  9 | GÃ¡s                        | NULL          |
| 10 | Ãgua                       | NULL          |
| 11 | Energia                     | NULL          |
| 12 | RetenÃ§Ãµes                 | NULL          |
| 13 | Fundo de Reserva            | NULL          |
| 14 | AtualizaÃ§Ã£o MonetÃ¡ria    | NULL          |
| 15 | HonorÃ¡rio AdvocatÃ­cio     | NULL          |
| 16 | Pagamentos a Menor          | NULL          |
| 17 | Pagamentos a Maior          | NULL          |
| 18 | Fundo de Obras              | NULL          |
| 19 | Rateio Extra                | NULL          |
| 20 | Acordo                      | NULL          |
+----+-----------------------------+---------------+
```

**Resultado**

```
+----+-----------------------------+---------------+----+------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id |       nome_categoria        | id_condominio | id | ano  | id_categoria | id_condominio | mes_01  | mes_02  | mes_03  | mes_04  | mes_05  | mes_06  | mes_07  | mes_08  | mes_09  | mes_10  | mes_11  | mes_12  |
+----+-----------------------------+---------------+----+------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | Cotas do MÃªs               | NULL          |  1 | 2018 |            1 |            19 | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  | 200.95  |
|    |                             |               |  2 | 2019 |            1 |            19 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 |
|  2 | Juros                       | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  3 | Multas                      | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  4 | Descontos                   | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  5 | Tarifa bancÃ¡ria            | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  6 | Rendimento de PoupanÃ§a     | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  7 | Rendimento de Investimentos | NULL          |  3 | 2018 |            7 |            19 | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 250.00  | 600.00  |
|  8 | Multas InfraÃ§Ãµes          | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  9 | GÃ¡s                        | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 10 | Ãgua                       | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 11 | Energia                     | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 12 | RetenÃ§Ãµes                 | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 13 | Fundo de Reserva            | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 14 | AtualizaÃ§Ã£o MonetÃ¡ria    | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 15 | HonorÃ¡rio AdvocatÃ­cio     | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 16 | Pagamentos a Menor          | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 17 | Pagamentos a Maior          | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 18 | Fundo de Obras              | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 19 | Rateio Extra                | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 20 | Acordo                      | NULL          |    |      |              |               |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
+----+-----------------------------+---------------+----+------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você fazer um `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM Categorias a
LEFT JOIN Orcamentos b ON a.id = b.id_categoria
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Caso queira listar somente um ano especifico do orçamento, pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT * FROM Categorias a
LEFT JOIN Orcamentos b ON a.id = b.id_categoria AND b.ano = 2018
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Comment: Obrigado! Mas eu inserindo um WHERE pra listar um ano específico de um condomínio não retorna todas as categorias. 
Ex.: 

SELECT * FROM financeiro_categorias_receitas a
LEFT JOIN financeiro_orcamentos_receitas b ON a.id = b.id_categoria
WHERE b.id_condominio = 19 AND b.ano = 2018

ORDER BY a.id;

Comment: coloque no `ON`, vou alterar a resposta

Comment: Muto obrigado! Tudo certo agora.